# Deployment Status on object detail

Tags: standard-objects

Can we enable/disable Deployment Status of Standard Objects? How is it done?
I am referring to the deployment status seen in the "Details" of an object from "Object Manager".

I have two record types in "case" object on which I want to make this change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot change the deployment status on the standard objects. You can only make the changes to the deployment status only on the custom objects. And for record type we won't be having any deployment status . If you done want that particular record type you may deactivate it.